# Shortcodes / PHP disabled in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

The theme I'm using is Acid by Pure but that may not be relevant. The theme has a Portfolio section and shortcodes/php seem to be disabled on the Portfolio pages. Inserting a shortcode in the editor (in Text/HTML mode) results in the shortcode displaying on the page like [shortcode] rather than converting. Using do_shortcode does nothing even after trying different plugins to enable PHP in pages/posts. Adding do_shortcode directly to the single-portfolio.php file works, however I need to use a different shortcode on each different Portfolio entry. Is there something I should look for somewhere that would be disabling shortcodes that I can remove, or does anyone have any ideas on how to enable PHP in these specific Portfolio items as the plugins to enable PHP in posts/pages don't appear to affect this area.

Comment: I would provide some reference code to help answer this question. It could be that the shortcode is inserted incorrectly. If it's malformed it will just render as text.

Comment: The shortcode is correct, I've tried it along with a few others, also it works when inserted into do_shortcode and used in the loop. I cannot use it in the loop however because there is a different shortcode for each entry.

Comment: Supply more information.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Not sure I understand it. But the loop in the theme was:

```
<?php echo $the_content; ?>
```

But I changed it to the following and now shortcodes are enabled:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$the_content);?>
```